# Receiver type is forward declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7

I have this code (along with other stuff):

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext
{
    assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }

    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

These lines are giving me errors that class message is a forward declaration:

```
_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
```

What is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: I think you forgot to import the header file which you have declared like @class abcd

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You must import CoreData/CoreData.h in the file Supporting Files/YourApp-Prefix.pch:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#endif
```

Answer (score 11):

By forward Declaration means you must be declaring class by `@Class`  . Import the Class in the .h/.m file and hope so it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to the top of your .h or .m file

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by importing the #import "Project-Name-Swift.h" file in the Objective C class that uses a Swift class.

Answer (score 0):

I Change file DDXML.h and Work.

File: DDXML.h

Change:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE && 0 // Disabled by default
```

To:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE && 1 // Disabled by default
```

Answer (score 0):

This frequently happens to me after renaming a class,  and then forgetting to update @class myclass in a header file  (which obviously won't throw a compile error.)