# NSImage forward declaration error

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm trying to convert a NSURL to a NSImage but when I try to do so with the following code:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[myArray objectAtIndex:i]];
NSImage *myImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
```

xCode gives me the error "Receiver type 'NSImage' for instance message is a forward declaration. According to other SO posts, it's a problem with importing. However, I'm already importing my .h file as well as CoreData and I've tried using this:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#endif
```

from [Receiver type is forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238772/receiver-type-is-forward-declaration). I have no idea what to do at this point, I'm sure it's obvious but I cannot figure it out. My header for my .m file is

```
#import "myClass.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

and CoreData is being imported in the .h file. 
 Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Mac, you want AppKit rather than UIKit.

Comment: God dammit I knew it was simple. This is my first Mac app so I didn't even think about it. Thank you!